# while loop not working on second loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to take an integer for input and print it only if the number is <= 2000 or else the user is asked to re-enter the number again and again.

When I enter a number greater than 2000 it asks me to enter number again ( which is exactly what I'm trying to do ) and if I enter a number greater than 2000 **again** it does nothing. It seems that the loop is running forever but I don't know what I did wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code written in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main(){

unsigned int a = 0 ;
int out = 1;

cout << "Please enter a number : " << endl;

while (out){
    cin >> a;
    if (a > 2000) {
        cout << "Number is greater than 2000 !" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the number again : " << endl;
        cin >> a;
        out = 1;
    } else {
        cout << "Your entered number is : " << endl << a << endl;
        out = 0;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now seems like the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You have two `cin ...` lines; you need only one.

Comment: Do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does in all those places? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should debug my own program. Sorry for the trouble and thank you :)

Comment: is this guess my number game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and if I enter a number greater than 2000 again it does nothing

That is not right, it is waiting for you to enter the next `cin` input.Since you have two `cin`s in the loop for `a` values greater than 2000, the second `cin` doesn't get a prompt.

Your program can be simplified a lot, change the `while loop` part like below

```
while (out){
    cin >> a;
    out=a>2000?1:0;
    if(out)
       cout<<"Enter number again ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info !

Comment: @blackGreap Check the edit I have just made. Since you have two `cin`s in the loop for values greater than 2000, the second `cin` doesn't get a prompt.

Comment: So that's why it looped forever. Makes sense now. Thank you mate :D

Comment: Actually it wouldn't loop for ever. ;-) I am sure the point is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I havent tested it, but you could try this:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

int main(){

unsigned int a = 0 ;

cout << "Please enter a number : " << endl;

while (true){
    cin >> a;
    if (a > 2000) {
        cout << "Number is greater than 2000 !" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Please enter the number again : " << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Your entered number is : " << endl << a << endl;
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `if (a > 2000)`

do not cin, and your code will start working, the reason is that you don't need to input here because loop will do that for you.